# Compress Xamarin assemblies after decompression

Tags: android, dll, decompress, c#

I have an APK that has assemblies in a single blob file. I could extract them successfully using decompress-assemblies.

Is there anyway I can compress them again into assemblies.blob file or at least modify the APK to allow loading the the extracted DLL like older Xamarin APKs?

I seem to have found that the application checks for application_config.have_assembly_store value, if it's true, it only continues if there's an assembly blob. Any idea how to change this value inside the APK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unpacking and repacking Xamarin `assemblies.blob` + `assemblies.manifest` files you can use the Python based tool [Xamarin AssemblyStore Explorer (pyxamstore)](https://github.com/jakev/pyxamstore/).

#### Unpacking

Make sure your current directory contains the files `assemblies.blob` and `assemblies.manifest`.

```
pyxamstore unpack
```

This will create the directory `out` which will contain the decoded dll files.

#### Repacking

Enter the directory where you have execute  `pyxamstore unpack` and execute

```
pyxamstore pack
```

This will generate the two files `assemblies.blob.new` and `assemblies.manifest.new`. Just rename the two files to it's original names without `.new` and replace them in the APK file.

Finally don't forget to `zipalign` and resign (`apksigner`) your APK file.